# Disable default VPN ports on windows 500 and 4500

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, vpn, netstat

How do I disable the default listening VPN ports on windows machine?

When I type `netstat -an | findstr "500"` command on the windows command prompt I get to see default 500 and 4500 ports listening which is not letting me to open any VPN software as these ports are already opened.

`C:\Users\mn>netstat -an | findstr "500"
  UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*
  UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*
  UDP    [::]:500               *:*
  UDP    [::]:4500              *:*`

This might be weird but how to disable this on windows? need help.

When I try to run ike-scan.exe software, I get this error and need to disable default ports. Here is what I am doing,

`C:\Users\mn\Downloads\ike-scan-win32-1.9>ike-scan.exe
ERROR: Could not bind network socket to local port 500
Only one process may bind to the source port at any one time.
ERROR: bind: Address already in use`

Comment: Those are related to IPSec VPNs. Do you have any incoming VPN configured on that machine?

Comment: Updated the question. Yes this is IPSec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to stop the “IKE and AuthIP IPsec Keying Modules” (short name: “IKEEXT”) service. It’ll obviously break Windows’ IPSec VPN client until you start them again.

Comment: FYI : Under Windows XP (please don't judge me), this service is simply called "IPSEC Services".